# HID device is not added to google meet on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

for some reason I cannot add a HID device (headset with mute button) to Google Meet on Ubuntu 22.04.
I installed latest `google-chrome`, In settings of the meeting I click "Connect device", then I see a pop-up with a list of devices (I have only headset and it is recognized). I select it and click "Connect", however it is not added to the list of connected devices.

Any suggestion how to fix it?